# Big O complexity of the partition function derived from this code?

Tags: computational-complexity, integer-partitions, recursive-algorithms

I am not able to calculate the Big O complexity of the partition function given in the code below. I tried to calculate it by estimating the number of nodes in the tree.

So far, I've figured out that from the start node, there will be n children, each that can have n/2 children at most (since the 2nd layer will pick from min(n, max) which will be n/2 at most), and so the 2nd layer will have n/4 children at every node at most, giving the tree a height of at most log(n).

We can better this, the first level will have n nodes. The second level will have at most 0+1+2+..+lim+lim-1+...1 nodes, and so on (where lim is ceil(n/2)). That gives n^2 nodes at each level, a total of log(n) levels, with O(n) work being done at each node. So, the complexity I get is O(n^3 log(n)).

But, I am not sure of my calculations, especially because clearly getting an upper bound for the partition function is not an easy problem (this paper: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11139-007-9022-z#page-1 lists it as < c^(root(n)) ).

Can someone help?

```
int N = 0; 
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> results = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(); 
int[] scores; 

void partition(int n, int max, ArrayList<Integer> prefix) { 
    if (n == 0) { 
    results.add(prefix); 
    return; 
    } 

    for (int i = Math.min(max, n); i >= 1; i--) { 
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(prefix); 
        list.add(i); 
        partition(n - i, i, list); 
    }
}

public int solve(int[] scores) { 
    N = scores.length + 1; 
    this.scores = scores; 
    partition(N - 2, N - 2, new ArrayList<Integer>());
    return 0;
}
```

Source: http://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_solution&rm=310853&rd=14552&pm=11308&cr=22673583

Answer (score 1):

Excellent asymptotics on the partition function are known, keep searching. Roughly, the number of partitions of $n$ is $\exp\Theta(\sqrt n) $ (much more is known). For each partition you are doing a polynomial amount of work, so the number of partitions dominates your runtime, which is also of the form $\exp\Theta(\sqrt n) $.

Comment: I don't understand. The code takes only n^3 log(n) time, right? (which is clearly a tighter bound than exp theta(root (n)) )

So, where is the mistake?

Comment: @IngridMorstrad If it generates all partitions then it has to do some amount of work for each. Perhaps it doesn't generate all partitions?

Comment: It seems to, and it passed the system tests on topcoder, so I think the code should work correctly. Maybe my analysis (n^3 log n) is wrong. Could you verify?

Comment: @IngridMorstrad Since there are $\exp\Theta\sqrt n$ partitions, if your program does something for each partition, then any analysis which gives less than that must be wrong.

Comment: Yes, but can you help me find where the error might be? I've written a detailed post explaining my calculations.

Comment: Many things are wrong. For example, it is not true that the depth is logarithmic, since some partitions, indeed almost all of them, have superlogarithmically many parts. Another problem is that you seem to be adding rather than multiplying the branch factors.

Comment: I'm not sure what the "exp" part in front of the theta is supposed to mean. Isn't the whole expression supposed to be inside the theta?

Comment: @Norswap exp is the exponential function. Moving the big theta around everything would result in a different bound.